# How to bring back system bar in kubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, kde, kde5

After installing Kubuntu 16.04, I don't have the system bar which holds the application launcher, date and time and so on. I am only a basic Linux user so can the experts tell me how to remedy the issue.

[image: As you can see there is no system bar]

The image shows that there is no system bar and the system information such as plasma version. It would be amazing if somebody could fix this problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Plasma 5 - Add panel**

Right click the desktop - Unlock Widgets.

Right click the desktop - Add Panel > Default Panel.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click the top left angle icon menu. There is `add panel` option there. Its called `plasma widget` if I am correct. You can manage panels from there. In your screenshot it is the icon with 3 horizontal lines. If this one does not have this option, move it, the other one might be below it.